# "undefined reference to" one function in a C header but not another

Tags: c, eclipse, linker, header

I'm trying to run two seperate functions, defined in the same header:

```
void MIC3_WriteByte(PmodMIC3* InstancePtr, u8 cmd);
void MIC3_ReadSPI(PmodMIC3* InstancePtr, u8 reg, u8 *rData, int nData);
```

When I call them just like this, WriteByte works just fine-

```
MIC3_WriteByte(&microphone, byte);
MIC3_ReadSPI(&microphone, reg, byteArray, ndata);
```

But ReadSPI gives me an error when I run the linker:

```
main.c:84: undefined reference to `MIC3_ReadSPI'
```

If I recall my C correctly, this means that the function either isn't defined in the header or being linked improperly. But if that's the case, why does one function only defined in the header work and not the other?

More confusingly, if I intentionally malform the input to ReadSPI (say by only giving it 3 inputs), I get a different error message -

```
../src/main.c:84:5: error: too few arguments to function 'MIC3_ReadSPI'
```

How can it know how many arguments the function should have, but not that the function should exist? Is this some sort of artifact resulting from the first error being thrown by the linker and the second error thrown by the compiler?

Comment: "the function either isn't defined in the header or being linked improperly". It's the latter. You need to describe the files where the functions are defined and also the exact link command.

Comment: The number of arguments is determined by the compiler by reading the function header (defined in the header file that you successfully included into the source code). The implementation of the function is stored in the library that you failed to link _after_ compiling. The function header and the function implementation must match, but they are two different entities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following declaration in the header file is the function prototype, which describes the returned value type, the name of the function, the number and types of the parameters:

```
void MIC3_ReadSPI(PmodMIC3* InstancePtr, u8 reg, u8 *rData, int nData);
```

So if you reference this function in a C source file including the header file, you will raise an error when compiling the C file if you are not compliant with this description. This explains your `too few arguments` error.

Moreover, if this function is not *defined* in your project (function definition corresponds to the block of code to run when function is called), you will raise an error when linking your project because the linker must know the definition of everything you refers to. This explains your `undefined reference` error.

Conclusion: probably your function `MIC3_WriteByte` is well defined in your project, which is not the case for `MIC3_ReadSPI`.